# Select rows where at least the condition is present in 2 columns in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with one column of gene names and 4 columns of detection methods (that in this case I called them X1, X2, X3 and X4). I would like to select the rows where the genes are selected by at least 2 detection method. Example of the table is:

```r
Table:
Row   Gene   X1   X2   X3   X4  
 1      A     1    0    0    0
 2      A     0    0    1    0
 3      A     0    1    0    0
 4      B     0    0    1    0
 5      B     0    0    1    0
 6      C     0    0    0    1
 7      D     0    0    1    0
 8      D     0    1    0    0
 9      D     0    1    0    0
 10     E     0    0    1    0
 11     E     0    0    1    0
```

In summary, I want to select the rows 1,2,3 (Methods X1, X2 and X3 detected gene A)  and rows 7,8,9 where methods X2 and X3 detected gene D.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please share some code of what you already tried? Generally, you could just calculate the sum across X1:X4 for each gene and then filter on rows/genes where the sum is >=2.

Comment: An alternative would be to just count the column "Gene" since it seems that a gene appears as many times as it was detected, i.e. Gene A is detected 3 times, gene C is detected only once.

Comment: Note that in the OP's example, the Genes that should give a positive match are A and D, whose rows all add up to 1, not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show which genes were detected by two or more methods, this will work.

#### Short version:

if `zz` is your data.frame, then:

```
yy <- by(zz, zz$Gene, function(dat) {sum(apply(dat[,-c(1,2)], 2, any)) >= 2} )
zz[zz$Gene %in% which(yy),]
```

#### Long version

```
# load the data:
zz <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Row Gene X1 X2 X3 X4 
1 A 1 0 0 0
2 A 0 0 1 0
3 A 0 1 0 0
4 B 0 0 1 0
5 B 0 0 1 0
6 C 0 0 0 1
7 D 0 0 1 0
8 D 0 1 0 0
9 D 0 1 0 0
10 E 0 0 1 0
11 E 0 0 1 0")

# now check, gene by gene, whether at least two columns have at least one 1.
# note that the repeated any() statements can be replaced by a loop or  
# apply(), but for only four columns this works, is easy enough to type, 
# and much easier to understand
yy <- by(zz, zz$Gene, function(dat) {(any(dat$X1) + 
                                      any(dat$X2) + 
                                      any(dat$X3) + 
                                      any(dat$X4) ) >= 2} )

# or, the apply way, in case there are a lot of columns.
# "-c(1,2)" as a column index means "every column except the first two",
# so if the data has 3, 4, or 30 methods, this code stays the same.
yy <- by(zz, zz$Gene, function(dat) {sum(apply(dat[,-c(1,2)], 2, any)) >= 2} )

yy
zz$Gene: A
[1] TRUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
zz$Gene: B
[1] FALSE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
zz$Gene: C
[1] FALSE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
zz$Gene: D
[1] TRUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
zz$Gene: E
[1] FALSE
```

Now to find the matching rows to the Genes that got `TRUE` results.

Find the names of `zz` (A, B, C, ... ) that correspond to `yy` values of `TRUE`, and index the data.frame based on that...

```
which(yy)  # equivalent to which(yy == TRUE)
```

gives

```
A D 
1 4
```

and

```
names(which(yy))
```

gives

```
[1] "A" "D"
```

so...

```
zz[zz$Gene %in% names(which(yy)),]
```

gives

```
  Row Gene X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1    A  1  0  0  0
2   2    A  0  0  1  0
3   3    A  0  1  0  0
7   7    D  0  0  1  0
8   8    D  0  1  0  0
9   9    D  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! it works perfectly, I just change == by %in% because I was getting this warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" that %in% fixed

Comment: Whoops. Copy-and-paste timing mistake. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowsum` and `rowSums` to find those with more than 1 method and `%in%` to find the matched rows.

```
x <- rowSums(rowsum(zz[3:6], zz[,2]) > 0) > 1
zz$Row[zz$Gene %in% names(x[x])]
#[1] 1 2 3 7 8 9
```